# Exclude specific directories from being parsed by intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using [php-intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense) extension for my Visual Studio Code.

How do I exclude other folders from being parsed by this extension? As of now it only excludes `node_modules` and `vendor` folder.

Answer (score 3):

The extension does not seem to have any specific setting so, unless I'm missing something, the only way to accomplish that is the `files.exclude` directive. It should definitively work with all languages because it basically makes the file or directory totally disappear from the program.

Beware though of the consequences: you won't even see the folder in the file explorer, nor will it show in searches.

Comment: I've added var/run folder to the `files.exclude`. So, VS Code does not even show this folder int he files explorer. However, these files are still parsed:

    `Parsing file:///../var/run/classes/.../Page.php`

Answer (score 1):

There is an opened issue on the author's github. I've just added a comment to explain how to workaround it.

Please have a look to my comment: https://github.com/felixfbecker/php-language-server/issues/159#issuecomment-514581602

In brief, you can change the way the workspace files are scanned in this file :

C:\Users\USER\ .vscode\extensions\felixfbecker.php-intellisense-xxxx\vendor\felixfbecker\language-server\src\ **Indexer.php**

```
public function index(): Promise
{
    return coroutine(function () {
        // Old code using the rootPath
        //$pattern = Path::makeAbsolute('**/*.php', $this->rootPath);
        // My new pattern 
        $pattern = Path::makeAbsolute('**/*.php', 'C:/Users/[USER]/Projects/sources/app/code');

        $uris = yield $this->filesFinder->find($pattern);
        // ...
    });
}
```

Restart VS Code after saving the changes and it will only index the needed path.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will point out this does not EXCLUDE a folder, but allows you to specify a folder to include.  For a Laravel app, I ended up just modifying this line: `$pattern = Path::makeAbsolute('**/*.php', $this->rootPath.'\app');`